# How to solve special character issue of xlwing's RunPython VBA?

Tags: python, excel, encoding, special-characters, xlwings

Hope you are doing well, I have created a python code that works perfectly running through cmd or directly into VS Code. I was incorporating the code through VBA to run some portfolio position verification and analysis. Fast forward a few weeks back, IT changed windows defender access I guess and Objshell.RUN does not work anymore.

Now I am using xlwings addon and using RunPython function which works like a charm except for one specific code which contains a Dataframe with French special characters and a € symbol.

It seems that xlwings RunPython does not recognize the special characters and thus does not find columns, how can I solve this issue? The code works like charm except when it's run via xlwings.

link to the error : https://ibb.co/pyY64xm

The key error state that it cannot find the columns 'Quantité de titres' and 'Total en €' because the xlwings interpreter cannot read the special characters.

Many thanks

Tried changing the engine, encoding through python but it's not a python code problem but more of a xlwing addon problem.

Comment: Could you give some debugging info? Maybe a screenshot, or code that causes the issue. Thanks!

Comment: In the post of course.

Comment: **1st** Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. **2nd** Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. **3rd** You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python*): `'Quantité en €'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `'QuantitÃ© en â‚¬'`.